# Troubleshoot doubleclick DataGrid show values wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mouseevent

I have an interesting situation which I cannot resolve on my own. I am double clicking on a dataGrid and having a message box show the text of the row.  Unfortunately, I'm only able to get one cell at a time???

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="NAME SELECT" 
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Height="238.968"
    >
<Grid Width="337" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGrid x:Name="selectDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="333" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,0,117" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="FIRST NAME" Width="125" Binding="{Binding FNAME}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="LAST NAME" Width="125" Binding="{Binding LNAME}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="selectDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick_1" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbTest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="147,176,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbTest2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,176,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

</Grid>
```

C#:

```
    private void selectDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            var row = (DataGridRow)sender;
            TextBlock myTextBlock = selectDataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(selectDataGrid.CurrentItem)  as TextBlock;
            TextBlock myTextBlock1 = selectDataGrid.Columns[1].GetCellContent(selectDataGrid.CurrentItem) as TextBlock;

            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(myTextBlock.Text);

        }
```

So what happens in this example:
If I click on the 2nd column (LAST NAME), the message box will display the first column.  If I change the message box show to 'myTextBlock1' then by clicking the first column the message box displays the 2nd column. FRUSTRATING.  If I try show(myTextBlock.Text + myTextBlock1.Text) I get an exception stating null object.  It's as if I would need to click on both columns at same time???

I would like to have the values separately and ideally something like show(myTextBlock.Text + myTextBlock1.Text) would be nice because then I could choose to show only one or the other etc...

I feel like I'm close and just missing something really obvious.  I hope someone can help me troubleshoot this as I've been at it all night last night and this am.

UPDATE:  if I hold down ctrl and select both columns in the row, then show(myTextBlock.Text + myTextBlock1.Text) works.  I'm not sure how to force it to auto select an entire row???

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this saves someone some time:

here is what I had:

```
selectDataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(selectDataGrid.CurrentItem)
```

here is what works:

```
selectDataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(selectDataGrid.SelectedItem)
```

It was literally as simple as changing CurrentItem to SelectedItem. Live and Learn!